# How do I tell Maven and TestNG to run a specific test class and suite.xml file?

Tags: java, maven, testng

I want to be able to run a specific test class from my testng suite using maven. My test classes are dependent on parameters from the testngsuite.xml file. I can run `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=mysuite.xml` or `mvn test -Dtest=sometest`. Is there any way to combine these two?

This link shows how to do one of the other but not both.
[How do I tell Maven and TestNG to run either a specific test class or a suite.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243346/how-do-i-tell-maven-and-testng-to-run-either-a-specific-test-class-or-a-suite-xm)

Comment: `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=mysuite.xml -Dtest=sometest`?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. `-Dtest=sometest` overwrites `-DsuiteXmlFile` so the suite doesn't end up being run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suite files are used to define a test run.

That means if you want only one test, just write a dedicated suite file.

Comment: Is there a way then to run a specific method from a suite file? For example if a specific test failed and you wanted to just rerun that one method.

Comment: You can run a specific method with the appropriate suite: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml AND/OR you can rerun failed tests: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#rerunning

Comment: Thanks the failed test xml is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your *tesngsuite.xml* the following:

```
<test name="my_test_name">
    <classes>
        <class name="packageName.ClassName" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

and then run form maven your *testngsuite.xml* using *mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=testngsuite.xml*. 
Or if you want to your keep your original testngsuite.xml you can just create a copy of it and make modifications there and run from maven your *testngsuite2.xml*