# How to run a test class from multiple classes in a TestNG suite xml file using maven?

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

My question is actually a duplicate of [How do I tell Maven and TestNG to run a specific test class and suite.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774526/how-do-i-tell-maven-and-testng-to-run-a-specific-test-class-and-suite-xml-file) but I did not understand the accepted answer so asking again.

I have the same problem, when I try to run a particular suite using `clean  test  -DsuiteFile=Suites\Jquery.xml` it runs that suite which is fine. also `clean  test -Dtest=WebGuru99_2` runs that test class but when I try doing `clean  test  -DsuiteFile=Suites\Jquery.xml  -Dtest=WebGuru99_2`, it runs that class but it doesn't depend on the suite file now. I can give any suite file here and it will run the same test class, which defeats the purpose of having suite file.

POM.xml

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <suiteFile></suiteFile>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I believe we cant do this as it defeats the purpose of having a test suite.  If we have to do this, we must handle this in code explicitly which class to execute. But not sure if I am correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is because -Dtest overrides -DsuiteFile (-Dtest also overrides "include" and "exclude" methods in testng.xml ).
So "clean test -DsuiteFile=Suites\Jquery.xml -Dtest=WebGuru99_2" will always run WebGuru99_2 test and -DsuiteFile will be ignored.

I doubt if "clean  test -Dtest=WebGuru99_2" will run or not as you have to give the -DsuiteFile=Suites\Jquery.xml also as configured in pom

Comment: Yes 'clean test -Dtest=WebGuru99_2' would not work now as i have given it as variable in pom but if i put a suitfile name there, this works.